# FlexDashboard - Boxplot will not update based on inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, rendering, flexdashboard

**code:**

````
---
title: "Wage Comparison Between Ethnic Groups in the Technology     Sector"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
  vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, cashe = TRUE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(stargazer)
library(ggplot2)
library(vctrs)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

mywd <- "C:/Users/Quinc/OneDrive/Murray State/Spring 2021/CIS 361"
setwd(mywd)


myfile <- "survey_results_public.csv"

Alldata <- read.csv(file = myfile, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

SmallData <- dplyr::select(Alldata, Respondent, Employment, Country, Ethnicity,     DevType
                    , YearsCode, CompTotal, WorkWeekHrs, Age, Gender)
SmallData <-na.omit(SmallData)

FromUSA <- SmallData %>% filter(Country == 'United States', Employment ==     'Employed full-time')

#Remove rows with null values
FromUSA <- na.omit(FromUSA)

#Narrowing the scope of DevTypes
FromUSA[] <- FromUSA %>% 
  group_by(DevType) %>%
  arrange(DevType)
i <- 0
while (i <= 533){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Academic researcher"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 1490){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Data or business analyst"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 2000){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Data scientist or machine learning specialist"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 2943){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Database administrator"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 3620){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Designer"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 12083 ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Developer"
  i = i + 1
} 
while (i <= 12200 ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "DevOps specialist"
  i = i + 1
} 
while (i <= 12221 ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Educator"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 12433  ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Engineer"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 12465 ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Product manager"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 12488  ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Scientist"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 12537 ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Senior executive/VP"
  i = i + 1
}
while (i <= 12541 ){
  FromUSA$DevType[i] <- "Student"
  i = i + 1
} 

FromUSA$YearsCode[grepl("More than 50 years",FromUSA$YearsCode)]<-'55'
FromUSA$YearsCode[grepl("Less than 1 year",FromUSA$YearsCode)]<-'1'
FromUSA$YearsCode <- as.numeric(FromUSA$YearsCode)

DevTypeVsEthnicity <- FromUSA %>% 
  select(c(DevType, Ethnicity, WorkWeekHrs, CompTotal, Age, YearsCode)) %>%
  group_by(DevType, Ethnicity) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(NumberOfPeople = n(), AveragePay = mean(CompTotal),     AverageHrsPerWeek = mean(WorkWeekHrs), AverageAge = mean(Age),     AverageYearsExperience = mean(YearsCode))


#DF (Ethnicity, DevType, AveragePay)
DevType_Ethnicity_Pay<- DevTypeVsEthnicity %>%
  dplyr::select(Ethnicity, DevType, AveragePay)


#DF (Ethnicity, DevType,AverageYearsExperience)
DevType_Ethnicity_Exp <- DevTypeVsEthnicity %>%
 dplyr::select(Ethnicity, DevType,AverageYearsExperience)

FlexData <- dplyr::select(FromUSA, Ethnicity, DevType,CompTotal)

EthnicCount <- FromUSA %>% 
  select( c(Ethnicity, CompTotal, WorkWeekHrs, Age)) %>%
  group_by(Ethnicity) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(NumberOfPeople = n(), AveragePay = mean(CompTotal),     AverageHrsPerWeek = mean(WorkWeekHrs), AverageAge = mean(Age))


DevType <- FromUSA %>% 
  select(c(DevType, Ethnicity, WorkWeekHrs, CompTotal, Age)) %>%
  group_by(DevType) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(NumberOfPeople = n(), AveragePay = mean(CompTotal),     AverageHrsPerWeek = mean(WorkWeekHrs), AverageAge = mean(Age))

AnovaDevtypeEthPay <- DevType_Ethnicity_Pay %>% 
  group_by(DevType, Ethnicity) %>%
  get_summary_stats(AveragePay, type = "mean")


EthnicityList <- as.list(AnovaDevtypeEthPay$Ethnicity)
DevList <- as.list(AnovaDevtypeEthPay$DevType)

```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Your Choices

```{r input}
selectInput("Ethchoice", label = "Ethnicity", 
            choices = EthnicityList, selected = "
            ")
selectInput("DevChoice", label = "DevType",
            choices =  DevList,
            selected = "" )



```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Ethnicity

```{r}
options(scipen=999)


    renderPlot({
ggboxplot(AnovaDevtypeEthPay, x= input$EthChoice, y = "mean") +
  labs(y = "Average Pay", x = "Ethnicity")  
})

```
````

DashBoard:
http://127.0.0.1:4036/Flex_Dashboard.Rmd

I cant figure out how to get my plot to update based on the Ethnicity and Devtype compared to AveragePay. I might need to create a second graph but can someone help me figure out how to get the boxplot to update and show the correct Average pay based on the inputs. Thank you.
Note:
"mean' = AveragePay

[AnovaDevtypeEthPay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S3JT.png)

Comment: You need to make your code reproducible. All your resources are local, and therefore unavailable. 

Guidelines for reprex: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help

Comment: that dashboard link is not valid, as it is pointing to your own local computer, *127.0.0.1*